# Einstein's Theory of Relativity Time Dilation

Tags: time, relativity

My friend claims that this proves that time moves faster on a mountain than at sea level.
He says that since both of these people start and end at the same angular position and are both traveling at the speed of the Earth's rotation, yet person 2 travels more distance (has a greater arc) then the time of person 2 relative to person 1 must be faster in order to keep the velocities equal.

Is this pseudo-proof correct? Do these equations hold for this scenario? Is this supported by Einstein's theory of general relativity?

Thanks!

[image: Time dilation proof]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ... and no.

It's true that the person on the mountain moves faster than the person on sea level. From Special Relativity, we therefore expect the person on the mountain to experience slower time. However, this effect is extremely small - so small that it's overcome by the effect of general relativity. In GR, the person at the *lower* gravitational potential (i.e. at sea level) is the one to experience slower time. The effect of GR isn't orders of magnitude larger than SR's, but it's enough to change the sign (i.e. who is the person that experiences slower time).

You can read more about experimentally testing this at the Wikipedia article on [Hafele–Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment).